# Android Can you get the width of the actionbar menu button collapsed?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an app that uses localisation and wanted to know if I could get the width of the collapsed actionbar menu button? it is only on phones that don't have a menu button such as the nexus 5. I want to know if it is even possible as sometimes my localisation is too large for the room it has and I want to be able to scale it correctly but can't if I don't know the width of the collapsed menu button. I use a custom title bar as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/title_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="title" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/Hearing_Test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/info_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:onClick="infoView"
    android:src="@drawable/info" >
</ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.